What should I do to get rid of waswasa
As-salamu alaykum, I have recently been dealing with waswasa and it is very hard to ignore, What should I do to deal with this and get rid of my waswasa Insallah

Here are some ideas,

Listen to the Quran or read anything Islamic that comforts you
Make Dua to Allah
Go for a walk

